# TestCaseSource attribute reads all the test data's of existing tests even if we run only one test.

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

My requirement: I want to read multiple TestData for single case and execution with all TestData should happen by itself.

TestCaseSource attribute provides these requirement but not exactly.

Using TestDataSource it is fetching TestData of tests which need not to be executed.If 100 tests are there and running on one test it is fetching TestData of all tests.

Solution needed as: Is there any possible way to read the TestData for each test while each test start executing.

Worst case solution: Single loop for all tests under class is considerable.

If dividing tests into multiple category and while running tests based on category, it is fetching the data for other tests from different category.

How I have implemented:

OleDbConnection is used for connecting with excel.
For each class separate excel document is used.
For each test separate worksheet is used.
Multiple test data is given in separate rows.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a long-talked-about but unimplemented feature of NUnit, which we call "dynamic test cases."

The name "dynamic" is probably not the best choice, since it can mean lots of things, but it is what we have been using. It means precisely that the data for test cases is not loaded and the cases themselves are not generated until point of execution. With such a feature, things would work the way you want, with only the data being loaded for the cases you choose to execute.

But with existing "static" test cases (also a pretty bad name) **all** the cases are loaded before we select which ones to run. If you can imagine a GUI runner, this is what you would expect to see: all the tests displayed before executing any of them. In fact, that's why the design is as it is: to support runners that need to display all the cases first.

There are a lot of design issues with the "dynamic" feature and there's no need to go into them here. You are looking for a workaround that will help you today.

The most general workaround, I'm afraid, is for you to stop doing what you are doing. That is, postpone making the connection to the DB until the test class begins its execution. This is only possible if the **number** of cases is otherwise known to you. This may be equivalent to the looping approach you are talking about.

Other options may be available depending on how you actually run your tests: nunit3-console, vs adapter, etc. If you edit your question to indicate what applies, I'll try to come up with alternatives.

UPDATE (14 March 2018):
The framework accepts a package setting of "LOAD" (all caps) with a value consisting of an `IList` of the tests you want to run. Normally, you would use either the full name of a class or a namespace containing multiple classes.

Bad news... none of the runners currently support this option. I have filed an issue on this at https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/384 Feel free to chime in there.